# Divs Aren't in Correct Position Until Browser Width Changes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been working on this website that is being run through wordpress for quite a long time now.  The basis of my problem is caused by this jquery system I created that displays divs after other divs and then changes their `nth-child` position based on the viewers browser width. So I have a loop in wordpress that displays all of my thumbnails for posts in a div called "doublearticlewrapper". By default, there are 4 divs / thumbnails that are being displayed in rows.. and overall there are 64 divs / thumbnails (a lot I know!).

Then with jQuery I'm creating these 6 extra divs that are essentially advertisement spots, these divs are called "doublearticlewrapperadmp".  They are being displayed after the main thumbnail divs via jquery and `nth-child`. Here is the jQuery Code for this repositoning `nth-child` jQuery system:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var $window = $(window);
var resized=false;
var resized500=false;
var resized600=false;
var resized700=false;
var resized800=false;

var sadfdsf=true;
var theDivs={
"div1": makeSpecialBox("doublearticlewrapperadmp", 'morecode'),

"div2": makeSpecialBox("doublearticlewrapperadmp", 'morecode'),

"div3": makeSpecialBox("doublearticlewrapperadmp", 'morecode'),

"div4": makeSpecialBox("doublearticlewrapperadmp", 'morecode'),

"div5": makeSpecialBox("doublearticlewrapperadmp", 'morecode'),

"div6": makeSpecialBox("doublearticlewrapperadmp", 'morecode'),

};

function makeSpecialBox(className, content) {
// Create a new special box with the class name and the content
var specialBox = $("<div />").addClass(className).html(content);
// Return the special box
return specialBox;
}

function removeSpecialBoxes() {
// Get the special boxes
var specialBoxes = $("#wrapper div").filter("[class^=doublearticlewrapperadmp]")
// Remove the special boxes
specialBoxes.remove();
}

function setNthPosition(theDiv,newPos){
// Generate the special box
var theClone=theDivs["div"+theDiv].clone();
// Append the special box after the nth-child
$("#wrapper div:nth-child("+newPos+")").after(theClone);
}

function checkWidth() {
var windowsize = $window.width();
if (windowsize >= 1442) {
    //if the window is in between the sizes of 440 and 500px
    //if(resized==false){
        // Remove special boxes
        removeSpecialBoxes();
        // Reposition
        setNthPosition(1,7);
        setNthPosition(2,15);
        setNthPosition(3,29);
        setNthPosition(4,37);
    setNthPosition(5,51);
    setNthPosition(6,61);
        resized=true;
  //  }
}

var windowsize = $window.width();
if (windowsize > 1022 && windowsize < 1441) {
    //if the window is in between the sizes of 500 and 600px
   // if(resized500==false){
         // Remove special boxes
        removeSpecialBoxes();
        // Reposition
       setNthPosition(1,7);
        setNthPosition(2,15);
        setNthPosition(3,29);
        setNthPosition(4,37);
    setNthPosition(5,51);
    setNthPosition(6,61);
        resized500=true;

   // }
 } 

if (windowsize > 479 && windowsize < 1023) {
    //if the window is in between the sizes of 600 and 700px
   // if(resized600==false){
        // Remove special boxes
        removeSpecialBoxes();
        // Reposition
        setNthPosition(1,7);
        setNthPosition(2,11);
        setNthPosition(3,23);
        setNthPosition(4,28);
    setNthPosition(5,39);
    setNthPosition(6,48);
        resized600=true;

    //}
}

 if (windowsize <=479) {
    //if the window is in between the sizes of 600 and 700px
   // if(resized700==false){
        // Remove special boxes
        removeSpecialBoxes();
        // Reposition
        setNthPosition(1,10);
        setNthPosition(2,20);
        setNthPosition(3,30);
        setNthPosition(4,40);
    setNthPosition(5,50);
    setNthPosition(6,60);
        resized600=true;

    //}
}

}
// Execute on load
checkWidth();
// Bind event listener
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

It's a very long code, but basicaly, this code creates 6 divs called "doublearticlewrapperadmp" that are being displayed in specific positions via `nth-child` and then repositioned if the viewers browser width is in one of my four specified widths.

All of this code does its job accept for one deal-breaking thing... The jQuery divs (doublearticlewrapperadmp) aren't being displayed in their correct position until the browser is resized a pixel or you inspect element in google chrome.  It's a real shame since my website is dependent on making this jquery code work properly.

Here is my site (I couldn't copy and paste eveything into a jsFidle since theres quite a bit of PHP code):

http://www.motodz.com (resize the browser a pixel or two, or inspect element in chrome to see the grey advertise boxes shift positions)

My site is an online motcross news website that is currently in a developmental phase... There are a few extra gaps or spaces depending on the viewers browser width, but I will fix this.  The divs that are being displayed via jquery are the grey box's that say "advertise here". These divs are called "doublearticlewrapperadmp". Try resizing your browser a pixel, and watch how the divs move into their correct `nth-child` position. These divs ARE supposed to reposition (and do reposition) when the viewers browser width changes into one of my specified widths, but they are in the incorrect positions by default.  So...

**The Situation:**

- I have divs that are being placed after my loop divs / thumbnails via jQuery & `nth-child`.
- These divs reposition or change `nth-child` positions based on my four browser width ranges.

**The Problem:**

- The divs aren't being displayed in their correct `nth-child` position until the browser width is resized a pixel, or you inspect element in Chrome.

So how would I fix this so that the divs that are being displayed via jQuery are in their correct `nth-child` positions by default?  Any help would truly, truly, truly be appreciated! :)

**PHP Loop Code:**

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

.doublearticlewrapper code for thumbnail posts go here

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**///Update:///**

I changed the appropriate divs to classes instead of ID's.. this somewhat stopped the flickering problem when the browser width changes. AND I also created a jsFiddle to showcase the problem. I copied and pasted the exact jQuery code and pasted the main CSS code as well. Here is the jSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Rs3wt/4/ (please resize the HTML window so there are 4 divs in a row)

The jSfiddle actually works properly (besides the subtle flickering). And here is why it works properly. By default.. The first ad div comes after the 7th article div, then the second comes after 15th, the third after the 29th, and the fourth after the 37th. These are all the correct positions I specified in my jQuery code. Now, if you goto my website:

http://www.motodz.com

The first ad div comes after the 7th div (like it should) but then the second ad div comes after the 16th (instead of 15th) div, then the third comes after the 31st(instead of 29th) div, then the fourth ad div comes after the 40th(instead of 37th) div.

If you visit my website, look at any ad div after the first ad div and then resize the browser or inspect element in google chrome to watch them shift into their correct positions.

So the problem here is that on my website, the ad div boxes load after the 7th, 16th, 31st, and 40th divs instead of loading after the 7th 15th, 29th and 37th divs like how I specified them to do so in the jQuery code and how they load in the jsFiddle demo.

I don't know why they would load in different spots in Wordpress as apossed to jsfiddle, I tried stripping down all my other jquery codes to see if their was another code causing this to load incorrectly, but it did not work. Maybe it has something to do with the loop and that it creates copies of the same div, where as in jsfiddle, I manually entered in all the divs.  I don't know, but any help would truly be aprecciated guys. :)

Comment: There's a rogue closing at the end there, so I'm guessing this is all within a document.ready function ?

Comment: @adeno yes, I forgot to add that to the code, I edited it now :)  Could that in some way be the source of the problem?  I really don't know.

Comment: Nope, not really, the last two lines where you call the function should be within a document.ready, the rest don't really have to, but it should'nt make it "not work". I've visited the site, and it does seem to work for me, I see no difference in my Chrome browser when resizing.

Comment: I think it might be a little difficult for the community to understand exactly where these advertisements are showing up initially and where they should be showing up instead. When I tested the site, the advertisements seemed to be positioned after the nth child that was specified in the `checkWidth` method. The main visible issue I noticed was a flickering of the empty image which is likely an effect of it being reloaded due to the cloning. That, and you should use classes instead of IDs for things like `doublearticlewrapper` and its children given that they are not uniquely named.

Comment: @RubenInfante Thanks for the support so far guys, I took your advice Ruben and changed the appropriate div ids to classes.. the problem still remains though.  I actually managed to throw together a jsfiddle.. check the updated question (bold letters that says update).. a lot of new info there.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with the additional information. It made it clear what you expected to see and what you are actually seeing. One other thing that might help further is seeing what the loop you are talking about at the end of your update is actually doing. Is that JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: @RubenInfante the loop code is done thru PHP. I posted the code for it above my edit section if it helps... I just really want to get this working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core cause of the issue is that the [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector is not behaving as intended on initial load, when the advertisement items are added to the DOM. It is essentially ignoring them.

If you were to count how many non-advertisement items there are prior to each of the advertisements, the numbers make sense.

To get around this, I suggest you move to utilizing the [`:nth-of-type()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) selector in the `setNthPosition()` method.

```
function setNthPosition(theDiv, newPos) {
    // Generate the special box
    var theClone = theDivs["div" + theDiv].clone();
    // Get the nth-child
    var nthChild = $("#wrapper > div:nth-of-type(" + newPos + ")");
    // Append the special box after the nth-child
    nthChild.after(theClone);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rN64Y/3/) - **new method** using `:nth-of-type()`

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rN64Y/1/) - **original method** using `:nth-child()`

Comment: I'm literally in shock right now.  I was 100% sure this issue would never be fixed.. I don't even know what to say right now.

Comment: Hey Ruben, I ran into a minor issue with getting DFP ads to change size on browser width change, here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423189/changing-ad-size-based-on-browser-width-in-dfp  If you could help me getting it working, that would be more than amazing! :)